# Show only specific branch on branch selection during queue build

Tags: azure-devops

Can I hide some repo branches on branch selection when running a pipeline? I need only a specific branch to only show up as a selection (see image below).

[image: branch select option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I hide some repo branches on branch selection when running a pipeline?

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this time.

If you want to limit to select the branch for the build, you could add the condition for the job:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```

[image]

In this case, the pipeline or the job will only build for the branch **master**.

Please refer the document [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples) for some more details.